# Relationssymbole (≥, ≤ u.a.) in Texten

Tags: single-word-request, mathematics

In einem Text (auf einer Website in diesem Falle) möchte ich gerne (je nach Situation) eine der 3 folgenden Optionen, bei denen die Zahlenwerte jedoch variabel sind, angeben:

1. „Die Bildhöhe muss ≥ 500 px sein.“
2. „Die Bildhöhe muss ≤ 500 px sein.“
3. „Das Bild muss genau 500 px hoch sein.“

Ich habe mich zwar mittlerweile dafür entschieden, das Ganze ein wenig umzuformulieren (in die Richtung von „Das Bild darf maximal 500 px hoch sein“), aber die eigentliche Frage bleibt offen: **Wie würde ich in so einem Text das Symbol ≥ durch ein Wort ersetzen?**

Comment: _Die Bildhöhe muss 500 Pixel **oder mehr** betragen_ wäre auch noch vertretbar, zumal es eindeutig `≥` und nicht `>` beschreibt, aber die Varianten von @Takkat sind stilistisch schöner. Das gilt auch für Substantivierungen wie _Mindesthöhe_ oder _Maximalhöhe_, wobei _Höchsthöhe_ schon fast verlockend seltsam ist.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Eine sprachlich weniger mathematisch klingende Alternative, die man erwägen kann, wäre:

> **≥ muss mindestens**: Das Bild muss mindestens 500 px hoch sein.
>   **≤ darf höchstens**: Das Bild darf höchstens 500 px hoch sein.
>   **= muss genau**: Das Bild muss genau 500 px hoch sein.

Comment: Das sind im Grunde die Formulierungen, für die ich mich auch entschieden habe. Danke.

Answer (score 8):

Ausgeschrieben heißt es **"größer oder gleich"**. Umgangssprächlich wird es auch oft zu *"größer gleich"* verkürzt.

Comment: Hmm. Natürlich, das klingt ziemlich logisch. Ich bin nur auf die Kurzform gekommen, und die klang für mich (Als Muttersprachler) nicht gut, daher bin ich auf das "oder" gar nicht mehr gekommen :D Danke!

Comment: "Größer oder gleich" ist leider grammatikalisch immer ein wenig
unhandlich, da eigentlich "größer" mit "als" + Nominativ
und "gleich" mit Dativ gebraucht wird, und man sich nun für eine
der beiden Möglichkeiten entscheiden muß. Bei "mindestens" gibt
es diese Probleme nicht.